# go > how to refactor http handler from main

Tags: go, refactoring, mux, gorilla

I'm learning go language and I still have some lack of knowledge. I'm writing  http static server (in 1st phase to serve assets). Also I'm trying to use gorilla/mux package as router.

So far I ended up with

```
pagekage main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "html"
    "net/http"
)

func HomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q", html.EscapeString(r.URL.Path))
}

func main() {

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)
    r.PathPrefix("/public/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/public/",
        http.FileServer(http.Dir("public/"))))

    http.Handle("/", r)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}
```

it works fine and serves all files under /public/

Now I'd like to refactor code

```
r.PathPrefix("/public/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/public/",
            http.FileServer(http.Dir("public/"))))
```

to be in form

```
r.PathPrefix("/public/").Handler(PublicHandler)
```

It's quite basic and I'd like to learn how to make better looking code.

Can you advice on this? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Simply assign the handler to a variable:

```
PublicHandler := http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public/")))
r.PathPrefix("/public/").Handler(PublicHandler)
```

Comment: Hi JimB, yes I know that I can do is as you wrote above. I'm thinking to move PublicHandler := http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public/"))) to its own function. And this step causing me difficulties.

Comment: @Jaro: Please post an example of what you're really asking. There's no reason you can't return PublicHandler from a function.